# How can the rules that determine valid user passwords be changed?

Tags: password, log, administration

Are there any particular rules on what a valid password is, speaking of length, upper- and lower and/or special characters, numbers, etc. and if so how they can be changed?

Comment: Do you think you could rephrase your question? I've read it a few times, but I still don't quite understand what it is you're asking.

Comment: I think the question is if there are any rules what a valid password is, and if so how they can be changed. I agree the question should be rephrased.

Comment: Correct, fixing it.

Answer (score 4):

Password strength rules are defined in the pam configuration in /etc/pam.d/, usually using the pam_cracklib module. However, the minimmum password length of 6 is hardcoded in the pam_unix module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of your question, but it sounds like you're asking about passwords not being changed when you change the user account password - I'm assuming you mean external passwords in things like mysql?

From what I understand, the user account password only changes the password used to login to Ubuntu (and the sudo password for your account).